# How to use Django Ratelimit with generics.ListAPIView?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-views, django-rest-framework

I want to use [Django Ratelimit](http://django-ratelimit.readthedocs.io/en/v1.0.0/usage.html) to limit the number of calls to a view. I am using `generics.ListAPIView` for a view; Is there a way to use Ratelimit with generics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why wouldn't you just use DRF way to throttle your API calls ([Throttling](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/))

Comment: Didn't know it existed! Thanks